Anchor invoke transfer query
key is pubkey hard coded
let key = Pubkey::from_str("7ErNjJnJySrLQVuScmgxA6xsaw9sxfihXy8necaSBt6h").unwrap();

 invoke(
    &transfer(&buyer.key(), &key.key(), lottery.ticket_price),
      &\[
         buyer.to_account_info(),
         key.to_account_info(),
         ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
         \],
     )?;

ERROR:
the method to_account_info exists for struct Pubkey, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
--> src/lib.rs:56:21
|
56 |                 key.to_account_info(),
|                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on Pubkey due to unsatisfied trait bounds
--> src/pubkey.rs:87:1
|
= note: doesn't satisfy _: AsRef<AccountInfo<'_>>
|
= note: doesn't satisfy _: ToAccountInfo<'_>
|
= note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey: AsRef<anchor_lang::prelude::AccountInfo<'_>>
which is required by anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey: anchor_lang::ToAccountInfo<'_>
Requirement:
Transfer the SOL to Vault Pubkey and from there to PDA account, as i am new to anchor it is hard to fix

